# crop square image after get app gallary

Tags: swift, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in swift. I made simple iphone app. Use this link: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Open-Image-Gallery-and-Take-photo-in-Swift and my app worked perfect. **I want my app to select cropable image like facebook or telegram.** 
Like this:

[image]

**My code:**

```
private func showBottomActionSheet(){

    let chooseOptionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openCamera()
    })
    let choosePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openGallary()
    })

    let findImagesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Find Images", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Clicked Find Images")
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })

    chooseOptionMenu.addAction(takePhotoAction)
    chooseOptionMenu.addAction(choosePhotoAction)
    chooseOptionMenu.addAction(findImagesAction)
    chooseOptionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(chooseOptionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func openGallary()
{
    self.picker!.allowsEditing = false
    self.picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
        self.picker!.allowsEditing = false
        self.picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.picker!.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        presentViewController(self.picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Not Found", message: "This device has no Camera", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.choosenPhoto = chosenImage
    DefaultUser.setUserImage(chosenImage)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I found objective c code but didn't find code for swift 2. 
Plz, advise me. thanks !

Comment: Are you asking for an implementation of `findImagesAction`?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey what is method this findImagesAction ? how to use this method. plz give me example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a circular cropping component for UIImagePicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196861/add-a-circular-cropping-component-for-uiimagepicker)

Comment: @Islam Q. thanks answer. i will try to use RSKImageCropper. if you have any example for swift, plz give me

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't, but I don't think it's hard to convert from ObjC once you know what you're doing.