# Update to Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 3.0 via Carthage

Tags: alamofire, swift3, xcode8, carthage

I am trying to update Alamofire to version 4.0. When I run carthage update I get many errors when building Alamofire scheme. It looks like files weren't updated to Swift 3.0 syntax. What I am doing wrong? Log from terminal:

```
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.0.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/ls/6t_b5mqx5s187hq2dtts6ys00000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.ORghi2.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire watchOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:36:1: error: expressions are not allowed at the top level
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:36:5: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:74:5: error: expected declaration
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:74:9: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:77:5: error: expected declaration
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:77:9: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:80:5: error: expected declaration
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:80:9: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:83:5: error: expected declaration
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:83:9: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:89:5: error: expected declaration
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:89:9: error: consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/liborzapletal/Documents/Aplikace/PNG/PNG/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift:92:5: error: expected declaration
....... and many others
```

I am using carthage version 0.18. I tried delete carthage Build and Checkout folders. I have set Xcode 8 version as default. For now without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in terminal default Xcode was still 7. I checked it by command:

```
xcodebuild -version
```

which returns:

```
Xcode 7.3
Build version 7D175
```

In system it looks like default is Xcode 8.0 but not in terminal. So I use command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode\ 8.app/
```

And now it's working.